# Java - method.Invoke only works on one class

Tags: java, methods, invoke

I have run into a problem as soon as I tried to make a Java application which I want to make modular. I want to have an implemented system for events, however, the events which I want to call only call from the file which the whole system starts on. I tried two things mainly: Invoking Methods on their parent classes, and invoking methods by getting them from the class. Here is the code:

```
    static HashMap< String, ArrayList< Method > > GameEventDatabase;
static HashMap< String, ArrayList< String > > GameEventDatabaseT;
static HashMap< String, ArrayList< String > > GameEventClasses;
public static void CreateDatabase() {
    EventHandler.GameEventDatabase = new HashMap< String, ArrayList< Method > >();
    EventHandler.GameEventDatabaseT = new HashMap< String, ArrayList< String > >();
    EventHandler.GameEventClasses = new HashMap< String, ArrayList< String > >();
}

public static void CallEvent( String EventName, Object[] args ) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException{
    if( GameEventDatabaseT.containsKey( EventName ) && GameEventClasses.containsKey( EventName ) ){
        ArrayList< String > methods = GameEventDatabaseT.get( EventName );
        if( methods == null ){
            EventHandler.CallEvent( "GAME_Alert", new String[] {"Fatal","The specified event '"+ EventName +"' was loaded as a 'null'. Please report this to the developer, located at: Techdaan@gmail.com"});
        }else{
            for( int i=0; i<methods.size(); i++ ){
                System.out.println( EventName );
                //methods.get( i ).invoke( Class.forName( GameEventClasses.get( EventName ).get( i ) ).newInstance() , args );
                try {
                    Class.forName( GameEventClasses.get( EventName ).get( i ) ).getMethod( methods.get( i ), Class.forName( GameEventClasses.get( EventName ).get( i ) ) ).invoke( methods.get( i ), args );
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                }
                System.out.println( "Called " + EventName + " in the class " + GameEventClasses.get( EventName).get( i ) );
            }
        }
    }else{
        EventHandler.CallEvent( "GAME_Alert", new String[] {"Fatal","The specified event '"+ EventName +"' could not be found, or the class index could not be found. Please report this to the developer, located at: Techdaan@gmail.com"});
    }
}
public static void NewEvent( String EventName, String MethodName, String classname ){
    if( GameEventDatabase.containsKey( EventName ) && GameEventClasses.containsKey( EventName ) ){
        GameEventDatabaseT.get( EventName ).add( MethodName );
        GameEventClasses.get( EventName ).add( classname );
    }else{
        ArrayList< String > TempArray = new ArrayList< String >();
        TempArray.add( MethodName );
        GameEventDatabaseT.put( EventName, TempArray);
        ArrayList< String > TempArrayTwo = new ArrayList< String >();
        TempArrayTwo.add( classname );
        GameEventClasses.put( EventName, TempArrayTwo );
    }
}
```

Now if I register an event, it works fine:

```
            EventHandler.NewEvent( "GAME_Alert", "Alert", "com.gmail.techdaan.pixldtowns.Core.Initialize" ); //From Initialize - Main class
        EventHandler.NewEvent( "GAME_Tick", "HandleGameTick", "com.gmail.techdaan.pixldtowns.Core.Initialize" ); // From Initialize - Main class
```

Those two work fine if I call them, however, if I call another event from the "Tick event", which runs once every 1/60th second, it doesn't reach it somehow. No errors at all.

```
    public DrawMainMenu( JFrame Frame ){
    this.gameFrame = Frame;
    setGameBGColor( Color.WHITE );
    try {
        EventHandler.NewEvent( "MENU_DrawMainMenu", "UpdateMainMenu", "com.gmail.techdaan.pixldtowns.Graphics.DrawMainMenu" );
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    }
}

public void UpdateMainMenu(){
    System.out.println( "b" );
    if( new File( "Resources/interface_login.png" ).exists() ){
        System.out.println( "Yup =)");
    }else{
        System.out.println( "Nope =(");
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: a few comments: 1. try to use the Java naming conventions (like starting variable names with a lower case character), it makes your code much easier to read. 2. You don't show the whole class, but all those static methods indicate a bad design. 3. *Never* ignore Exceptions. (unless you reallyknow what you are doing), and 4. This not what reflection is for. Use Interfaces instead method.invoke().

Comment: Hi, regarding "it doesn't reach it somehow." Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: Good point, Thomas, I forgot about CamelCase. I am used to camelCase. About the other things, I will be sure to catch the exceptions properly, and come back here. Thanks!